# How to write a PLY interface for hand-written lexer?

Tags: python, ply

I'm writing a compiler in Python, and I made a hand-written lexer, because I can't figure out how to parse indentation in PLY. Also, my lexer uses some `yield` statements like so:

```
def scan():
...
    for i in tokens:
        if i[0]: yield Token(self.line, i[0] if i[0] in keywords else "ident", i[0])
            elif i[1]:
                 if "e" in i[1]:
                     base, exp = i[1].split("e")
                     val = float(base) * 10 ** int(exp)
                 else: val = float(i[1])
                 yield Token(self.line, "float", val)
        ... other cases ...
```

However, I realized that the PLY parser requires a `token` method, so I made one that looks like this:

```
def token(self):
    return next(self.scan())
```

The actual scanning using `scan()` takes an average of 124 ms, according to my tests, but when I use the PLY parser, the parsing doesn't start after a few minutes. It appears that my `token()` method has a problem.

Also, I tried to rename the `scan()` method so that *it* could become the interface. Python returns something like

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'type'
```

So it appears that PLY needs a method that will return a single token at a time.

Is there any way to rewrite the `token()` method so that it would return the next iteration of `scan()` and not be that slow?

Comment: By the way, you can use PLY for most lexing even if you want to parse indentation. Just carry all (leading?) whitespace newlines through the lexer and postprocess the token stream to insert proper INDENT/DEDENT tokens. When I did this, I didn't use PLY for the parsing step, so I didn't have to integrate it and hence can't answer this question. But it does make writing the lexer easier IMHO.

Comment: @delnan That could _probably_ work, but what I also can't figure out is how to return multiple tokens for that one rule to process indentation. The rest I could code already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your generator somewhere, like:

```
def start(...):
   self.lexer = self.scan()

def token(...):
    return next(self.lexer)
```

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about PLY.

Comment: It works, but it definitely makes the program go quite a bit slower, about 5ms. But that doesn't really bother me. Thanks!